# Is the author messing up the notation or am I thick?

Tags: tensors, index-notation

In Arfken and Webber's "Mathematical Methods for Physicists" under the topic "General Tensors" the following is given:
$$dx^i=\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial q^j}dq^j$$
or in vector form,
$$d\textbf r=\vec\epsilon_jdq^j$$
such that $$\vec\epsilon_j=\frac{\partial\textbf r}{\partial q^j} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  (1) $$

Till here things are fine,

he then writes $$\vec\epsilon_1=\bigg(\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial q^1},\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial q^2},\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial q^3}\bigg) $$

But shouldn't it be$$\vec\epsilon_1=\bigg(\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial q^1},\frac{\partial x^2}{\partial q^1},\frac{\partial x^3}{\partial q^1}\bigg) $$ from $(1)$?

**EDIT:** I am adding the screenshot (though I have included the relevant details in the question) just for the sake of completeness and clarity.

[image]

Comment: How does it continue after that? Is it only for that one line?

Comment: The last expression he has mentioned just once and actually before introducing equation (1).

Comment: @AHusain Please look at the picture.

Comment: I agree with you. It should be the $dq^1$ coefficient.

Comment: @J.G. Thank god. Later, you will see him calculating Christoffel symbols. I wanted to confirm that the Left-Hand Side matches the Right-hand side in one of the equations. I took his misprinted definition and wrote the 9 components on both sides, spent almost an hour trying to figure out why the LHS was not matching the RHS!

Comment: This kind of typo is liable to happen when an author only half-shows indices, as in differentiating a bold vector with respect to an index component of a vector. It makes a matrix, but only one of its two indices appears. It helps to make your own notes that show everything.

Comment: @J.G. Just one more thing: Is $$\frac{\partial q^i} {\partial x^k} \frac{partial x^k}{\partial q^j}=\frac{d q^i}{d q^j}$$ ?

Comment: Yes. In other words, $\delta^i_j$.

Comment: @J.G At places, the book has written the RHS of above as $\frac{\partial q^i}{\partial q^j}$ instead of the total derivative.

Comment: Come to think of it, it really should be a partial derivative.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131693/discussion-between-lost-and-j-g).